# How to add apache2 , php and mySql to eclipse?

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 ,i'm new to Ubuntu,I already installed apache2 , php and mySql . Now I want to add these to eclipse so that I can work on this IDE . Please help me I will be glad if you provide commands to add or i can add using application.
also please suggest some of the developers tools and softwares for web development.

Answer (score 0):

You do not add these to eclipse - they run independently as servers (`apache/php and mysql`)

Download and install eclipse specifically built for web development from [PHP Development Tools](https://eclipse.org/pdt/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did exactly what you suggested.Now how can work on eclipse ? How to write my code in php so that I can open it on my server which is installed on my system ? please can u show a single example ?

Comment: little google research shows this: http://www.phpeclipse.com/ i am sure you'll find plenty of resources around. If you lack theory of client-server model there is a multitude of books covering php programming subject. There are many courses teaching this subject too. Simply put your question has no simple and easy answer you need to spend some time learning.  Luckily php/eclipse is simple programming system: in eclipse you open folder from where your apache server serves files, you create php files in that folder and run them in browser by navigating to your file.